# Swift Concurrency: Conforming a 3rd party library to actor isolation

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, actor, swift-concurrency

I am in the process of converting some code bases over to using Swift concurrency and am running into a few snags along the way.

The current project I'm working through has a few 3rd party libraries that it relies on, and in one of those libraries, there is a delegate protocol that requires some data values to be returned from its methods.

Here is an example of the type of delegate methods in the library:

```swift
public protocol FooDelegate: AnyObject {
    func foo() -> CGFloat
}
```

I'm attempting to return some values from the implementation of the protocol like this:

```swift
extension ViewController: FooDelegate {
    func foo() -> CGFloat { // <- Cannot satisfy requirement from protocol
        view.bounds.height
    }
}
```

Without any modification, the above is implicitly isolated to the MainActor and can not satisfy the requirement from the FooDelegate protocol.

One solution I've tried was to mark the function implementation with `nonisolated`:

```swift
extension ViewController: FooDelegate {
    nonisolated func foo() -> CGFloat {
        view.bounds.height // <- Cannot be referenced from a non-isolated context
    }
}
```

This did not work though because it references the view controller's view. That results in the `view` being referenced from a non-isolated synchronous context. (*There are also a few other issues with this since any values that are passed through into any of the delegate functions need to conform to `Sendable` to be able to be passed across actors*).

My question is, is there a way to take a 3rd party library and extend it somehow so that it conforms to proper actor isolation without having to modify its source code?

Comment: Can you provide a sample project that can reproduce this issue? From your snippets, I am not facing any problem.

Comment: @SoumyaMahunt - You need to set the "Strict Concurrency Checking" build setting to "complete" to see this warning.

Comment: @RPK - Did you find a solution? I'm facing this with some of Apple's older macOS protocols, such as `QLPreviewPanelDataSource` and `QLPreviewPanelDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MainActor.assumeIsolated {}`:

```
extension ViewController: FooDelegate {
    nonisolated func foo() -> CGFloat {
        MainActor.assumeIsolated {
            view.bounds.height
        }
    }
}
```

From the docs:

```
/// A safe way to synchronously assume that the current execution context belongs to the MainActor.
///
/// This API should only be used as last resort, when it is not possible to express the current
/// execution context definitely belongs to the main actor in other ways. E.g. one may need to use
/// this in a delegate style API, where a synchronous method is guaranteed to be called by the
/// main actor, however it is not possible to annotate this legacy API with `@MainActor`.
```

Available: macOS 14.0, iOS 17.0, watchOS 10.0, tvOS 17.0