# Swift concurrency compliant warning using an objc class DTGridView

Tags: swift-concurrency

I’m attempting to convert an old project to be swift concurrency compliant. I’m using an old objc class DTGridView, and have separated out the DataSource & Delegate into MainActor classes. On compilation (SWIFT_STRICT_CONCURRENCY = complete) I see the warnings of ‘Main actor-isolated instance method ‘*' cannot be used to satisfy nonisolated protocol requirement, Add 'nonisolated' to ‘*' to make this instance method not isolated to the actor on the following methods in DataSource class

```
func numberOfRows(in gridView: DTGridView) -> Int {
var noRows: Int = 0
                let gridIdentifier = gridView.gridIdentifier
                if gridIdentifier == "HeaderEigenValues" || gridIdentifier == "HeaderEigenVectors" || gridIdentifier == "MainEigenValues" {
                    noRows = 1
                }
                else if gridIdentifier == "MainEigenVectors" || gridIdentifier == "LeftEigenVectors" {
                    noRows = 3
                }
                return noRows
}
func numberOfColumns(in gridView: DTGridView, forRowWith index: Int) -> Int
func gridView(_ gridView: DTGridView, heightForRow rowIndex: Int) -> CGFloat
func gridView(_ gridView: DTGridView, widthForCellAtRow rowIndex: Int, column columnIndex: Int) -> CGFloat
func gridView(_ gridView: DTGridView, viewForRow rowIndex: Int, column columnIndex: Int) -> DTGridViewCell!
```

Now this compiles and runs, however I want to prepare for swift 6, and struggling to find away to return values asynchronously in a synchronous method.

In the Delegate class, I use

```
nonisolated func gridView(_ gridView: DTGridView, selectionMadeAtRow rowIndex: Int, column columnIndex: Int) {
        Task {
            await clearFloatingTextField()
…
         }
}
```

since there is no returning value requirement, Task{} works readily.

I’ve tried to use Semaphore techniques researched from this website, in order to retrieve relevant value, but these methods get stuck in waiting for return value.

Admittedly I am just coming to terms with this new protocol, so maybe missing something fundamental. I have made a small project using UITableView in a UIController again separating out the DataSource & Delegate into @MainActor classes, compiling SWIFT_STRICT_CONCURRENCY = complete, and don’t see these nonisolated protocol requirement warnings in these 2 classes, what am I missing?

Comment: Answer in post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70386294/swift-concurrency-conforming-a-3rd-party-library-to-actor-isolation?rq=2